# Solution for codewars kata "are they the same" works unproperly (php)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I was trying to solve the kata called "are they the same". When I tap test, everything's working properly. However, when I try to attempt the answer, it says, I have wrong answers (for example true, when the right answer is false)

The kata

> Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (orcompSame(a,
> b)) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with
> the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b
> are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.
>
> Examples Valid arrays a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]   b =
> [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361] comp(a, b) returns
> true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the square of 121,
> 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the square of
> 161, and so on. It gets obvious if we write b's elements in terms of
> squares:
>
> a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  b = [11*11, 121*121,
> 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19] Invalid arrays If, for
> example, we change the first number to something else, comp may not
> return true anymore:
>
> a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]   b = [132, 14641, 20736,
> 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361] comp(a,b) returns false because in b 132
> is not the square of any number of a.
>
> a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]   b = [121, 14641, 20736,
> 36100, 25921, 361, 20736, 361] comp(a,b) returns false because in b
> 36100 is not the square of any number of a.
>
> Remarks a or b might be [] or {} (all languages except R, Shell). a or
> b might be nil or null or None or nothing (except in C++, Crystal,
> Dart, Elixir, Fortran, F#, Haskell, Nim, OCaml, Pascal, Perl,
> PowerShell, Prolog, PureScript, R, Racket, Rust, Shell, Swift). If a
> or b are nil (or null or None, depending on the language), the problem
> doesn't make sense so return false.
>
> Note for C The two arrays have the same size (> 0) given as parameter
> in function comp.

Here is my code

```
function comp($a1, $a2) {


if(!isset($a1) || !isset($a2)) return false;
  if(is_null($a1) || is_null($a2)) return false;
  if(empty($a1) && empty($a2)) return true;
  if(!$a1 && !$a2) return false;
  $match = false;
  foreach($a2 as $num2){
    $match = false;
    foreach($a1 as $num1){
      if($num2 < 0){
        $match = false;
        break(2);
      }
      if($num2 == (float)$num1*(float)$num1){
        $match = true;
        break;
      }
      else{
        $match = false;
      }
    }
    if($match == false){
      return false;
    }
  }
  if($match == false){
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Can you please help me find the problem. I tried a lot of stuff and have no clue what is working unproperly.

Comment: What you did is checking "for every element x in B, sqrt(x) is in A". What the question asked, if I understand it correctly, is that "if x is in B y times (y may be 0), sqrt(x) must be in A y times too".

Comment: Square `a`, and sort it. Sort `b`. Compare the results.